# RoR edit and new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model

I have two actions: **new** and **edit**, these call in view a partial named **form**.

**new** (view):

```
<h1>New Item</h1>
<%= render partial: 'form' %>
```

**edit** (view):

```
<h1>Edit Item</h1>
<%= render partial: 'form' %>
```

**form** (partial):

```
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
<% f.field_for :foo %>
<% end %>
```

The model have a **big particularity** with id field in database, it's a compose column but in a single. I explain:

I have a items tuple:

```
id       | name              | foo
----------------------------------
10001000 | Name of item 1000 | bar
10001001 | Name of item 1001 | bar
10011000 | Name of item 1000 | bar
10021000 | Name of item 1000 | bar
10021001 | Name of item 1001 | bar
```

The first four digits of id column come from *ficticious* item_type_id column, and the next four digits are *item_id*. This f**k table can't be altered.

When run **/items/new** I dont have a problem, because the form generated its right action html property.

```
<form action="/items/new" method="post">...</form>
```

But, when I run **/items/edit** the form generated its like this:

```
<form action="/items/10021001/edit" method="post">...</form>
```

And its needed to be generated like this:

```
<form action="/items/1001/edit" method="post">...</form>
```

The first part of id column **1002** come from a session variable.

I'm using a trick from routes.rb

```
resources :items
```

I don't know if I be explained properly, I'm taking english lessons yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override to_param method in Item Model.

```
def to_param
  "#{id % 10000 }"
end
```

Comment: it's easy than like looks?

I'm wishing to arrive to the office for proof.